# Passing a std::pair templated with two template arguments as a parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am writing a function, insertPairIntoVector, that will insert a std::pair into a std::vector based on a comparison of the second element in the pair. My prototype looks like this:

```
template <typename T, typename Q>
std::vector<std::pair<T, Q>> sortPairIntoVector(
    std::pair<T,Q>, std::vector<std::pair<T, Q>>);
```

And my function definition looks like this:

```
template <typename T, typename Q>
std::vector<std::pair<T, Q>> sortPairIntoVector(
    std::pair<T, Q>, std::vector<std::pair<T, Q>>) {

}
```

but I am still getting a ton of ambiguous errors regarding templates. Any help as to what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: `Any help as to what I am doing wrong?` For starters, not showing any code that calls the function, and not showing any error messages you claim you see. We are not clairvoyant. I strongly suggest you create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -5, accepted):

When two ">" characters are near each other, they need a space in between so that it is not interpreted as the ">>" operator. After doing that change, the prototype compiles.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename Q>
std::vector<std::pair<T, Q> > sortPairIntoVector(
    std::pair<T,Q>, std::vector<std::pair<T, Q> >);
template <typename T, typename Q>
std::vector<std::pair<T, Q> > sortPairIntoVector(
    std::pair<T, Q>, std::vector<std::pair<T, Q> >) {

}

int main() {
}
```

Comment: This has been fixed in C++11 -- which is what the question is specifically tagged with.

Comment: This is tagged as c++11 so that shouldn't be an issue.